# How to get subslices?

Tags: rust

I have a variable `a` of type `&[T]`; how can I get a reference to a subslice of `a`?

As a concrete example, I'd like to get the first and second halves of `a`, provided `a.len()` is even.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You use slicing syntax for that:

```rust
fn main() {
    let data: &[u8] = b"12345678";
    println!("{:?} - {:?}", &data[..data.len()/2], &data[data.len()/2..]);
}
```

(try it [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=94a489149a2ba0898a058acbb68250d9))

The general syntax is

```
&slice[start_idx..end_idx]
```

which gives a slice derived from `slice`, starting at `start_idx` and ending at `end_idx-1` (that is, item at the right index is not included). Either index could be omitted (even both), which would mean zero or slice length, correspondingly.

Note that if you want to split a slice at some position into two slices, it is often better to use `split_at()` method:

```rust
let data = b"12345678";
let (left, right): (&[u8], &[u8]) = data.split_at(4);
```

Moreover, this is the only way to obtain two mutable slices out of another mutable slice:

```rust
let mut data: Vec<u8> = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];
let data_slice: &mut [u8] = &mut data[..];
let (left, right): (&mut [u8], &mut [u8]) = data_slice.split_at_mut(4);
```

These are explained in more detail in [the official book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-03-slices.html).