# How to get subslices with neither panicking nor unsafe?

Tags: rust

*Note: [How to get subslices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272673/how-to-get-subslices) is close, but without either constraint.*

I am looking for the best implementation possible of a function with this signature:

```
fn sub(slice: &[u8], range: Range<usize>) -> Option<&[u8]>;
```

which would have the same functionality as the `impl Index<Range<usize>>` but replacing the failure case with `None` instead of panicking.

The twists are the seemingly unusual constraints that this function should not:

- invoke functions that may `panic`
- use `unsafe` code

A careful investigation of the [`slice`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html) interface has brought to my attention:

- [`split_first`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_first) and [`split_last`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_last)
- [`split_at`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.split_at)
- `impl Index<Range<usize>>` (and variants)
- [`as_ptr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.as_ptr) and [`from_raw_parts`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/slice/fn.from_raw_parts.html)

However most are not suitable:

- `split_at` and `Index<Range<usize>>::index` may panic
- `from_raw_parts` is `unsafe`

Leaving me to implement `sub` as:

```
fn sub(slice: &[u8], range: Range<usize>) -> Option<&[u8]> {
    if range.start > range.end { return None; }

    let length = range.end - range.start;

    if length > slice.len() { return None; }

    if length == 0 { return Some(b""); }

    let mut slice = slice;
    for _ in 0..range.start {
        if let Some((_, s)) = slice.split_first() {
            slice = s;
        }
    }

    for _ in 0..(slice.len() - length) {
        if let Some((_, s)) = slice.split_last() {
            slice = s;
        }
    }

    Some(slice)
}
```

which while seemingly working has O(N) complexity; rather unsatisfying.

Is there any way to do better?

Comment: Any implementation of this in the standard library would be almost guaranteed to use `unsafe`; why are you so hesitant to use it yourself? Also, is there truly a difference between code which cannot panic and code that has a `panic!` call but which may **never** be executed?

Comment: @Shepmaster: Regarding `panic!`: there is a difference between statically knowing that no `panic!` can occur and dynamically hoping (with a test suite) that `panic!` should never occur. Notably, in the former case, there is a guarantee that code generation will not call the panic hooks (even if the tests were flaky). Regarding `unsafe`, this is indeed what I use at the moment, however I would prefer relying on the standard library for this assuming (perhaps innocently) that it is better tested and has been more thoroughly audited than my own code.

Comment: @Shepmaster: I would also note that the presence of `split_first` and `split_last`, which return `Option` had me quite hopeful that `split_at` would follow in their track. I am surprised at the discrepancy of interface here.

Comment: Someone has to write the code that is trusted (to use `unsafe` correctly) and it appears it's not yet in Rust's libstd.

Comment: @bluss: Certainly. To be honest I was surprised that `slice_at` did not return `Option<(&[T], &[T])>` in keeping with `split_first` and `split_last` interfaces.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Now you can just use the `get` method on the slice.

I copied the code below from [The document of that method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/primitive.slice.html#method.get).

```rust
let v = [10, 40, 30];
assert_eq!(Some(&40), v.get(1));
assert_eq!(Some(&[10, 40][..]), v.get(0..2));
assert_eq!(None, v.get(3));
assert_eq!(None, v.get(0..4));
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, and very nice answer. I'm glad to see my wishes came true!

Answer (score 8):

I'll start with the version that I prefer. It is `get_slice`, it uses bounds checked slicing, and you can look at the compiler's optimized output to verify that the compiler knows it will never panic. (**1.** I agree, “no panic” would be a terrific thing to be able to work with as an assertion; **2**. get_slice would be a nice addition to libstd and indeed is planned.)

```
/// Return the subslice corresponding to `range`, if it is in bounds
/// and well formed (start <= end).
pub fn get_slice(slice: &[u8], range: Range<usize>) -> Option<&[u8]> {
    if range.start > range.end || range.end > slice.len() {
        None
    } else {
        Some(&slice[range])
    }
}
```

Next is an attempted solution, that is still coded with what appears to be an *O(N)* algorithm, but is strength reduced to *O(1)* by the optimizer.

We use the slice iterator and the fact that we can convert it back to a slice. The slice iterator's `.nth()` is open coded to jump forward in constant time, but the reverse version is unfortunately not. However its loop is optimized out.

```
pub fn sub(slice: &[u8], range: Range<usize>) -> Option<&[u8]> {
    if range.start > range.end || range.end > slice.len() {
        return None;
    }

    let mut iter = slice.iter();
    let take_front = range.start; 
    let take_back = slice.len() - range.end; 
    if take_front > 0 {
        iter.nth(take_front - 1);
    }
    if take_back > 0 {
        (&mut iter).rev().nth(take_back - 1);
    }
    Some(iter.as_slice())
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=3152826696293a76514f6e73d151ab01&version=nightly&backtrace=1)

Note: I unfortunately think we are making a bit of arbitrary rules here. We could use `.chunks()` after the take front operation, and it would give you a direct *O(1)* solution. However, chunks may panic if you ask for 0-size chunks. That puts it in the same bracket at just using bounds checked slicing for me (“it may panic”).

Comment: Nice. Do you know if `nth` could be optimized to ensure O(1)?

Comment: On the case of panics, I just realized that we are using integer arithmetic which may panic when overflow checking is on. The `slice.len() - range.end` needs be rewritten with `wrapping_sub`. I could really benefit from a `no_panic` lint.

Comment: Removing all the panic cases with that methodology means writing code that is silent on error though; that's not better: it is worse. `get_slice` is much better than that, especially if it would come from libstd.

Comment: In this specific condition I would expect `wrapping_sub` to be correct since we already asserted (above) that `range.end <= slice.len()`. It's a panic that is already unreachable dynamically.

Comment: That's exactly how `get_slice` works. It uses bounds checked indexing, but it is unreachable dynamically. (And "statically", since the compiler removed the panic cases from the optimized code).